# How can I update a column in mysql table by inserting combination of text and values from other columns if its not null?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains 3 columns whose values can be null. I have to create a 4th column and concat value of only those columns that are not null.
Expected Output:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
----------------------------------------------------
1       0      1     col1=True;col2=False;col3=True;
0      Null    1     col1=False;col3=True
```

Comment: Why you need that? Sounds like a XY-problem. The fourth column `col4` has several issues, f.e. you always have to update it if the table is updated(even from ssms), it contains multiple informations in a single value(violation of normal form), it contains information that is already available,..)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, earlier I used to have 3 different columns for storing this info. Now I have made changes to my table that has a new column containing the summary of the previous 3 columns. But not sure how can I check null condition and concatenate on the basis of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat_ws()`:

```
select concat_ws(';',
                 concat('col1=', elt(col1 + 1, 'false', 'true')),
                 concat('col2=', elt(col2 + 1, 'false', 'true')),
                 concat('col3=', elt(col3 + 1, 'false', 'true'))
                )
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to write a script in the language of you choice in order to update the existing data.

And then include this routine in your application.